# What are these two revision numbers in 'svn info'?

Tags: svn, version-control

`svn info` for the whole codebase (not a particular file) gives me below output. I don't understand

- what is the difference between `Revision: 12838` and `Last Changed Rev: 12817`
- and how it can happen that these two numbers are different

Could someone explain?

```
Path: .
URL: svn+ssh://radek@repository.company.com.au/var/lib/svne2/edumate2/tags/4.0.1
Repository Root: svn+ssh://radek@repository.company.com.au/var/lib/svne2/edumate2
Repository UUID: edccd8aa-08f3-0310-ac9a-cddb71435de8
Revision: 12838
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: radek
Last Changed Rev: 12817
Last Changed Date: 2011-12-20 15:07:53 +1100 (Tue, 20 Dec 2011)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Revision" is the current revision (remember that all files in an SVN repo use the same revision number).  "Last changed" was the revision when this particular file was last changed.

Comment: `svn info` is for the whole directory. How come these revisions are different?

Comment: @Radek: Because there have been further commits to your repo since the directory was last modified.

Comment: So if the numbers are not the same it means that in the directory I did svn info is not the latest code?

Comment: One more question: What does Last changed" stand for if I do "svn info" on a directory?

Comment: @Radek: No, it means that something got committed to your repo outside of this directory.

Comment: @Radek: In the case of a directory, "last changed" is the last time anything in that directory got modified (it corresponds to what you'd see if you did `svn log` on that directory).

Comment: So if I do up the numbers `must be the same`?

Comment: @Radek: You mean `svn up`?  No, because there might be changes in places other than in that directory.

Comment: The directory in question is production website. It's a tag 4.0.1. `svn info` & `svn up` is performed on this directory. Now we are discussing how come these two numbers are sometimes different even after `svn up`.

Comment: @Radek: Yes, and like I've said, it's because there are other changes outside this directory.  Your tag is not the entire repository.

Comment: Like in another tag or branch, trunk?

Comment: Hmmmmm. So is there any way to know if have the latest code in specific directory? Without doing 'svn up'?

Comment: @Radek: You can use `svn status -u` (files with newer versions in the repository will be marked with a `*`).

Comment: I better create new question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So Revision >= Last Changed always? If so, would be handy addition to your already very clear answer.

Comment: @HeathRaftery I think Revision >= Last Changed might not be true all the time, I picture a repository with only one directory and if you do `svn info` there, I think they should be the same number. In bigger structures where the repo has different folders and sections that are working continuously in parallel, you never know if you're the last change (as in your directory tree) or they are (some other directory tree in the same repo), but that doesn't mean your code is outdated.